# Live audio-video streaming to server, using network internet (not wi-fi)

Tags: android, video, streaming, video-streaming, live

I want to create Android app, that will enable users to stream in real time audio and video from their phone to specified server. In addition, that server should save such recording to some file, to view it latter, but now it's not so important.
My question is: **are there any simple or well documented ways of streaming video to remote server** (not via wi-fi, I guess it can be important info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how well Android handles WebRTC currently but I recommend you check it out! It uses Web-Protocols alongside Javascript/HTML5 components to stream-video/audio in real-time via the web-browser. I use it in 2 of my projects for similar applications. The only thing that differentiates is that you are wanting to store the video on your server.I'm guessing would also be possible but I haven't tried it! You can find all the documentation [here](http://www.webrtc.org/).